# How to get DropDownList Value for a random Index?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Very important: I am NOT asking about SELECTEDValue from a SelectedIndex.

How do I get the value of any index when it is not the selected index? 
For example, the selected index might be 5, but I want to get the value of item 9.

Thanks.

Comment: `DropdownList` has got an `Items` collection which holds these values, check at the respective index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string value = DropDownList1.Items[8].Value;
```

That will give the value at that index.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `Items` collection for the DropDownList which holds the `ListItems` displayed in the dropdown.

you can access the same by using index as `ddl.Items[index].Text` or `ddl.Items[index].Value` and get the values, since it Zero based make sure you are passing in the right index else you may get  Index out of bounds exception

So if you are looking for the 9th value seen in the dropdown it would be available at index 8 in the collection